# Brightness doesn't work on an Acer Aspire 4750

Tags: acpi

I used Ubuntu 11.10 on Acer Aspire 4750 with Intel HD Graphics. When I made it up looks like Linux Mint 12, the graphics card was detected as Intel Sandy Bridge x86/MM2.

But I still got problem with the brightness. It didn't work, as I had to try some tricks like editing the GRUB, but it still didn't work. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if it will enable the brightness after a reboot:
Edit the file `etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add the line `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` to the Screen section.

E.g.

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection 
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

note : updated October 2016 with Ubuntu 16.10

Working fine on my Aspire 4750 since update to latest (X)Ubuntu 16.10
I add following into file /etc/default/grub :

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=on"

Additional : to setup the default brightness I setup file /etc/rc.local:

echo 75 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

Bye
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Proprietary drivers. Other than that, then it may be an issue with ubuntu not being able to control your monitor brightness